# There a infinity numbers of $n$ such that $ \phi (n) \equiv 0 \pmod{100} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I have no clue what this part: $ \phi (n) \equiv 0 \pmod {100} $  means. 
$0 \pmod {100}$ means I have an equivalence class $[0]$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. This also means I have $100, 200, 300 ,\cdots$ as the value of $ \phi (n)$.

Comment: Well,  it just means that you are to show that there are infinitely many natural numbers $n$ such that $100\,|\, \varphi(n)$.  For a hint note that $100=2^2\times 5^2$ so, using the standard formulas for $\varphi(n)$ try to build large families of good $n$.

Comment: It just means it is divisible by 100. Hint: $101$ is prime

Comment: I think the toughest part of this question is to show that there exists at least one number $n$ such that $100| \phi(n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All natural numbers n have a decomposition into prime factors. (Fundamental theorem of Arithmetic)

$n = p_1^rp_2^s\cdots p_{i}^z$

$\phi(n) = n (\frac {p_1 -1}{p_1})(\frac {p_2 -1}{p_2})\cdots(\frac {p_i -1}{p_i})$

If $100| \phi(n)$

Then $5^3$ must be a factor of $n$

In fact $\phi(5^3) = 4\cdot 5^2 = 100$

There exists at least one $n$ such that $100|\phi(n)$

For higher powers of $5,$ e.g. $\phi(5^4) = 500$

And for factor the factor 2, 
$\phi(2\cdot 5^3) = 2\phi(5^3)\cdot \frac 12 = 100$

$\forall j\ge 0, k\ge 3, \phi(2^j5^k) \equiv 0\pmod {100}$

Answer (score 0):

You may take this as a **Hint:**

Consider this sequence, does it have this property?

$1000,10000,100000,1000000,\cdots$. Or equivalently, $10^k, k>2, k\in \mathbb{Z}.$ In fact, values of $\phi(10^k)$ are multiples of $400$,

can you show  **Why?**

Answer (score 0):

Since $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$ for coprime $a,b$, it is sufficient to find some $a$ such that $\phi(a)=100$ and then all numbers $n=ab$ give $\phi(ab)\equiv 0\mod{100}$. Try $a=5^3$.